# Can I found more than one religion?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

My civilization has founded Christianity. Thinking I could corner the market on religion like I did in Civilization 4, I saved up faith to trigger another great prophet.

However, when the second great prophet spawned, there was no option to found a new religion:

- In the founding city for Christianity, there was only an option to enhance Christianity.
- In a city I controlled that had no religion, there was only an option to spread Christianity (i.e., the same option as a missionary).

The game continues to inform me that there are *n* religions left to be founded, but is it not possible to found more than one per civilization? If it is possible, what requirements are necessary to found religions after the first one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each civilization can only found one religion. After you found your religion, you can use great prophets only to enhance your religion (once), to build a religious tile improvement or to spread your religion (like a missionary, but much stronger).

In a standard game [1], the number of religions that can be founded is smaller than the number of civilizations. So there is some competition, not only to get the best beliefs (each belief can only be used by one religion), but to found any religion at all.

[1]: As far as I know, the number of religions depends on the map size. If you play with custom settings and turn down the number of civilizations, then there would be enough religions for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I've found nothing so far to indicate this is possible. As far as I can see each civilization in the game may only found at most one religion, and there aren't enough religions "slots" for each player, so don't be too slow or you'll not get to found one at all.

*Enhancing* the religion, as you've seen the option for, allows you to add two additional beliefs to it (a second Follower Belief and an Enhancer belief). Note that enhancing early gives you the advantage of choosing from more beliefs - each belief is only available to a single religion, so once another player selects a belief, it will not be available to you.

Additionally, only the majority religion in a city will confer the benefits from that religion's Follower Belief(s) to the city, so trying to support multiple religions would actually be counter productive in some ways.

Unless you have the piety perk 'religious tolerance' giving you the pantheon bonus from the second highest religion in a city.